# Accessing class symbol using dlsym

Tags: c++, casting, dlsym

I want to access a class symbol from my shared library(.so)
Is this the correct way I need to do it.

```
MyClass* pMyClass= (MyClass*)dlsym(phandle, "MyClass");
```

If this is correct way, then I should have my MyClass header for casting.
I want to know if there is any other way I can do this without including the header?

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify? You say "class symbol", but what you probably mean is "global variable of type "pointer to instance of class"". Is that so?

Comment: @Arkadiy: Yes, that is whai i need. However for compiling the above mentioned code I need to include MyClass header and I want to know if is it possible to avoid that?

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know what is `MyClass`, if you do not include the header. Also, what is `MyClass` actually, that is "pointed" by `phandle`? Object or class definition?

Comment: @KirilKirov: Thas what I wanted to know, if there is a workaround or is this impossible altogether?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Answer (score 2):

As you know, dlsym returns basically `void *` - an untyped pointer.

That pointer is an address of a symbol - just a number. If you have

```
class MyClass instance;
```

in your .so, dlsym will return the value of `&instance`. There is no other information there. To `dlsym`, `instance` is just an address of an area of memory. If you had

```
char instance[sizeof(MyClass)]
```

you'd get exactly the same value.

So, to answer your question - no, there is no knowledge of the contents of the symbol whose address `dlsym` returns. You have to add that knowledge yourself. That's why you have to cast the result of `dlsym` and that's why you need to include the header file.

Answer (score 2):

The only symbols you can get with `dlsym` are those which
correspond to something in memory: an object or a function.  The
name of a class is neither.  You can get a pointer to an object
of a class type, but you can't do anything with it (even name
the class type) without a header somewhere.  (You can use
a forward definition of the class at the point where you do the
`dlsym`, but since there's nothing you can do with a pointer to
an incomplete type, this doesn't buy you much over `void*`.)